# Is there a way to find notch position and size?

Tags: android, iphone, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I just realized that my unity app is not notch friendly an I need to move some UI buttons away from the notch to make them accesible

Is there a way to find the notch position and size on the screen?

Comment: Couldn't you just skip this problem by not setting the game to fullscreen, and letting the notification bar be displayed? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47072490/unity-how-to-disable-fullscreen-on-android-devices-s8

Comment: Yes i could, but it would be Way better to accomodate the UI to skip the notch if possible

Answer (score 3):

Check https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-safeArea.html: it doesn't describe where exactly on each device the notch is, but defines where it is safe to put your UI.
Also, there is a setting in the Player Settings (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsAndroid.html) called **Render outside safe area**. Uncheck that to avoid rendering stuff where it might be invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Use [NotchSolution](https://github.com/5argon/NotchSolution). You can even reference it directly in `packages.json` with the URL `git+https://github.com/5argon/NotchSolution.git`.